# Audio progress bar for Android

Tags: android

I have an audio program that I would like to add an audio progress bar with some kind of button, so that a user can grab the button to navigate through the audio forward or backward.

Is there any kind of standard component that does that? Or how can I make a custom one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SeekBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html).

To position and seek the audio, use [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)'s getCurrentPosition(), getDuration() and seekTo(int).